# How to store images into amazonaws server using php

Tags: php, upload

How i can store images into amazonaws server instead of storing on my hosting!

i have a PHP code that store images in my hosting/web dir. but i want to store them on amazon server!

PHP:

```
$targetfolder = "testfolder/";
```

i want to make target folder in amazon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of tutorials on this, but here is the general process

1. Create an AWS account (if you don't have one setup already)
2. Create a S3 Bucket
3. Create an IAM user **without** login permissions
4. Add a policy to the IAM user to allow permissions to view and add resources  the S3 bucket
5. Create security access keys for the IAM user
6. Use some method with the new security access keys to manipulate content in your bucket from your hosted server.

Methods to interact with your bucket include:

- The PHP S3 SDK https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/
- S3 REST API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/APIRest.html
- The `aws s3` cli application http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html

I suggest from the OP your best bet would be to use the PHP SDK.

Comment: thank you for the answer! .... is there any other free clouds like amazonaws ?????